# How to close current view after loading finish a webpage in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am doing this inside my `UIWebView` delegate. I want to close current `UIViewController` and all opened `UIViewControllers` when the success web page finished its loading.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
NSLog(@"URL----------%@",webView.request.URL.path);

[self.actindi stopAnimating];
if ([webView.request.URL.path isEqualToString:@"/success.php"]) {
    dm.isPaySuccesss=YES;

    [self closeit];
}

}
```

When I debug this happens. But  when I in my client's phone its not closing even the current view. Same OS version. mine is 6plus. His one is 6s.whats the reason for this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: To be able to help you please provide the implementation code for your method `closeit` and information how all these view controllers were presented.

Answer (score 0):

remove view with this

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Sorry I mean its a View controller,, I need to close the viewcontroller that webView is there